# Div does not adjust to content size

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a div and when I use the Chrome DevTools, the div (highlighted in blue) is smaller than its content. The black line shows the actual height of the div while the red line demonstrates how tall the div should be.

[image]

This is my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/cqsohhsr/):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="survey" class="survey"></div>
</div>
```

I think it is caused by the flex property of my cards, but I am not sure.

Comment: col-md-12 has margins. If you want a div with no margins use a row. If thats what you are expecting?

Comment: Thank's for you response. Sorry, i probably badly explained me. The problem is : my div recognize with a height of 150px (Blue highlight) but in reality it's content is longer (About 600px) but this is no recognize.

Comment: Do you let the children of the col-md-12 div float without clearing the float at the end? https://jsfiddle.net/nsypark2/

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem - with the code you have provided it is impossible to say and any answer will only be a guess

Comment: By the looks of things though you probably have a set height on the survey div

Comment: @Kaddath I add the entire content of my stylesheet and now the behaviour is visible on fiddle. I try to find in the part of css i added ...

Comment: @Pete Indeed, the behaviour come from a height define in card-deck class thank's !

Comment: That's ok.  For future reference, links to fidldle must be accompanied by enough code to reproduce the problem in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap 4 spacing `m-0`

```
<div class="col-md-12 m-0">

        <div id="survey" class="survey">

        </div>
</div>
```

Learn about `bootstrap-spacing`:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Thank's for your answer but this is not what i search. I would like to know why my actual div is smaller (height) than the real content ?